# How to use a Zephyr rest call to find the time when the teststeps were updated?

Tags: jira-zephyr

We have testcases stored in Zephyr for Jira.  When we update teststeps, the updated date on Jira issues does not get updated.  I assume tath information is saved on Zephyr.  I need to find all the testcases whose steps have been modified since a given date.  i would like to do it with a ZAPI call.

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the changes made to the tests step, you can navigate to Add-ons> Under zephyr for jira select "General information> you can see the audit history for the steps. Please let me know if this fulfills your requirement

Comment: Well I needed to use a ZAPI Call to get this infor.  I figured out how to do this along the same lines as your answer but using ZAPI.  See bwlow.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I figuured out:

1) call like:
https:///rest/zapi/latest/audit?entityType=TESTSTEP&maxRecords=100&offset=0

will give you the last 100 records from the audit where Test steps were changed.  You can inspect information like "creationDate" and issueKey from the response.
2) If you need to see additional audit lines, change, the offset, to multiples of 100.  You can stop once, creationdate is older than your cutoff date.